# Modifying Ola Hallengrens index maintenance script for deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock, maintenance, ola-hallengren

In a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise database without a true maintenance window, I would like to run [Ola Hallengrens script to optimize indices](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html).

Testing has shown that while indices are reorganized and rebuild (online rebuild) on this database, other processes can experience frequent deadlocks and timeouts.

I would like to avoid disturbing other processes as much as possible; the maintenance script can be rerun easily and without the users noticing, so it does not matter if the rebuild itself is cancelled.

Therefore I would like to modify the maintenance script

- to run at a low deadlock priority (`SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW`),
- to wait only a short time to acquire locks (`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT`),
- and possibly to automatically retry again after a short delay when an index reorganize or online rebuild is cancelled by a deadlock or lock timeout error (some sort of `WHILE ... TRY ... CATCH ...`).

I have started by adding `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW` at the start of indexOptimize.sql, and it seems to run just fine, but I am not sure whether I have added it in the right place. I am worried that I may be messing with things I do not fully understand.

What are the pitfalls in adding these three options?

Is there a particular danger I should be aware of, a reason why the script does not include this functionality already?

What is the right place to put the `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW` and `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` within the script, so that they will be observed for all reorganize and rebuild operation?

Comment: TomV meant: What Edition of SQL Server are you running? Enterprise or Standard Edition.

Comment: I just rechecked, the script runs on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise, v11.0.3128.0. I can use online rebuilds available in Enterprise. I cannot use "low priority lock wait" added in sql 2014

Comment: Why don't you just contact Ola and ask if/when he will add support for those features? Just to also note you could take a look at [Minion Reindex](http://minionware.net/reindex/) as it offers a bit more configuration options compared to Ola's...matches more to what you are wanting to do.

Comment: I hope you are petitioning the project manager for a true maintenance window.  Changing the oil on a car while still driving is going to lead to problems eventually.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an older, unanswered question and as such is likely no longer relevant to the current build of Ola's solution.